# Multiple JSON root elements - PHP

Tags: php, json

I am creating an array with some objects like the code below:

```
$eventos = DB::select('SELECT *
    FROM eventos
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC'); 
    foreach ($eventos as $evento){
        $produtos = DB::select("SELECT * 
        FROM produtos
        WHERE transaction_id = '$evento->transaction_id'"); 
        $eventos = array(
            'timestamp' => $evento->timestamp,
            'revenue' => $evento->revenue,
            'transaction_id' => $evento->transaction_id,
            'store_name' => $evento->store_name,
            'products' => array()
            ); 
            foreach ($produtos as $produto){ 
                $products[] = array(
                    'name' => $produto->nome,
                    'price' => $produto->preco,
                    );
            }
        $eventos['products'] = $products;
        echo json_encode($eventos);
    }
}
```

But my JSON is not valid: according to the validator, there was the error "Multiple JSON root elements". There should be

]

},

{

and not

]

}{

How can I achieve this?

```
 {

   "timestamp":"2016 1",
   "revenue":120,
   "transaction_id":334,
   "store_name":"Uai",
   "products":[

      {

         "name":"Black Shoes",
         "price":99
      }
   ]
}{  //ERROR here
   "timestamp":"2016 2",
   "revenue":250,
   "transaction_id":6665,
   "store_name":"M Mall",
   "products":[

      {

         "name":"Blue Shirt",
         "price":100
      },
      {

         "name":"Pink Pants",
         "price":150
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: You are using `$eventos` twice in your code for two different things - once for your DB result and once for your array...and you're using it simultaneously for those purposes. That is unlikely to end well.

Comment: echo once out of the loop. In the loop, cumulate an array , say `$res[]=$products;`

Comment: you are just displaying json one by one, just make an array of all your entries and `json_encode` this array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't echo a series of JSON documents, one after the other, that's not valid.

Instead you need to assemble a *final, singular array* and encode that as JSON:

```
$final = [ ];
$eventos = DB::select('SELECT *
    FROM eventos
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC'); 
    foreach ($eventos as $evento){
        $produtos = DB::select("SELECT * 
        FROM produtos
        WHERE transaction_id = '$evento->transaction_id'"); 
        $data = array(
            'timestamp' => $evento->timestamp,
            'revenue' => $evento->revenue,
            'transaction_id' => $evento->transaction_id,
            'store_name' => $evento->store_name,
            'products' => array()
            ); 
            foreach ($produtos as $produto){ 
                $products[] = array(
                    'name' => $produto->nome,
                    'price' => $produto->preco,
                    );
            }
        $data['products'] = $products;
        $final[] = $data;
    }
}

echo json_encode($final);
```

I don't know what `DB::Select` is, but if it's just a flimsy wrapper around something like `mysqli` or PDO then it's a problem if it doesn't support placeholder values. **DO NOT** inject data directly in your queries. Instead use placeholders like `?` and bind the values separately.

Your database driver, whatever it is, may already support this, so check that out immediately to avoid potential problems in the future.